# freehand drawing with transparent background

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d

I need to draw freehand but while saving that image everything should be transparent except the strokes that I have drawn with free hand.
Can anybody please suggest? I have looked at Apple sample DrawPad but it saves image with white background whereas I want the image with transparent background.

Comment: I have looked at drawpad sample by apple but it saves image with white background though i have made imageview background as clear color

Answer (score 0):

Apple sample DrawPad worked for me. Only thing I had to change the background colour to clear Colour for ImageView & save it in PNG Format.
Hope this help others!!!